# Can't connect to postgres installed from stable/postgresql helm chart

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, docker-desktop

I'm trying to install postgresql via helm. I'm not overriding any settings, but when I try to connect, I get a "password authentication failed" error:

```
$ helm install goatsnap-postgres stable/postgresql
NAME: goatsnap-postgres
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Jan 27 12:44:22 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
TEST SUITE: None
NOTES:
** Please be patient while the chart is being deployed **
PostgreSQL can be accessed via port 5432 on the following DNS name from within your cluster:
    goatsnap-postgres-postgresql.default.svc.cluster.local - Read/Write connection
To get the password for "postgres" run:
    export POSTGRES_PASSWORD=$(kubectl get secret --namespace default goatsnap-postgres-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode)
To connect to your database run the following command:
    kubectl run goatsnap-postgres-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.6.0-debian-9-r0 --env="PGPASSWORD=$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" --command -- psql --host goatsnap-postgres-postgresql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
To connect to your database from outside the cluster execute the following commands:
    kubectl port-forward --namespace default svc/goatsnap-postgres-postgresql 5432:5432 &
    PGPASSWORD="$POSTGRES_PASSWORD" psql --host 127.0.0.1 -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432

$ kubectl get secret --namespace default goatsnap-postgres-postgresql -o jsonpath="{.data.postgresql-password}" | base64 --decode
DCsSy0s8hM

$ kubectl run goatsnap-postgres-postgresql-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --namespace default --image docker.io/bitnami/postgresql:11.6.0-debian-9-r0 --env="PGPASSWORD=DCsSy0s8hM" --command -- psql --host goatsnap-postgres-postgresql -U postgres -d postgres -p 5432
psql: FATAL:  password authentication failed for user "postgres"
pod "goatsnap-postgres-postgresql-client" deleted
pod default/goatsnap-postgres-postgresql-client terminated (Error)
```

I've tried a few other things, all of which get the same error:

- Run `kubectl run [...] bash`, launch psql, type the password at the prompt
- Run `kubectl port-forward [...]`, launch psql locally, type the password
- Un/re-install the chart a few times
- Use `helm install --set postgresqlPassword=[...]`, use the explicitly-set password

I'm using OSX 10.15.2, k8s 1.15.5 (via Docker Desktop 2.2.0.0), helm 3.0.0, postgres chart postgresql-7.7.2, postgres 11.6.0

I *think* I had it working before (although I don't see evidence in my scrollback), and I *think* I updated Docker Desktop since then, *and* I think I saw something about a K8s update in the notes for the Docker update. So if I'm remembering all those things correctly, maybe it's related to the k8s update?

Answer (score 8):

Whoops, never mind—I found the resolution in [an issue on helm/charts](https://github.com/helm/charts/issues/19867). The password ends up in a persistent volume, so if you uninstall and reinstall the chart, the new version retains the password from the old one, not the value from `kubectl get secret`. I uninstalled the chart, deleted the old PVC and PV, and reinstalled, and now I'm able to connect.

Comment: You saved us hours, thanks